# Zxing barcode scanner doesn't open from my app

Tags: android, button, zxing

I've integrated Zxing barcode scanner by adding the package `com.google.zxing.integration.android` into my project and this code on my MainActivity.java file:

```
public static Button scanBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    scanBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_button);

    scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    ...
}
```

For some reason, when I click at the button (`scanBtn`) nothing happens. There is nothing in the log, and nothing happens on the screen.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a permission for the camera and it solved it.

Answer (score 1):

First add the following dependencies in your gradle file

```
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.1.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
```

Remove `com.google.zxing.integration.android`

Then change your `onClick` method like  following code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
     IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this);
                    scanIntegrator.setPrompt("Scan");
                    scanIntegrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
                    scanIntegrator.setOrientationLocked(true);
                    scanIntegrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
                    scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
}
```

it will instantiate scan , you can get the result of scan in `onActivityResult`

Like this

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            if (scanningResult.getContents() != null) {
                String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents().toString();
                String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName().toString();
            }

            Toast.makeText(this,scanContent+"   type:"+scanFormat,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Nothing scanned",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

[Here](https://github.com/sshuvro58/BarCodeScanner)  is a sample project using Zxing barcode scanner in android

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Can you try out this code and see if it works for you?

```
scanBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    new IntentIntegrator(this).initiateScan();  
                }
            });
```

Just add the code above in your onCreate instead of this:

```
scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
```

}

Let me know if this works for you :)